# find and store a string after a pattern.It is hanging when sending path of file using a variable in sed ` `

Tags: shell, unix, sed, string-matching

disk/file1:

```
parameter wanted = 108,
```

From file1 I want to get value of wanted i.e 108 and store it in val. For this I used

```
val=`sed -n 's/.*wanted = \(.*\)\,.*/\1/p' disk/file1`
```

and it's working.

Now I want set this path to a variable and pass it same as above. But its not happening.

Code:

```
set pa=disk/file1 
val=`sed -n 's/.*wanted = \(.*\)\,.*/\1/p' $pa`
```

How to pass $ values in `   `?

Comment: I think you want `val="$(echo $pa | sed -n 's/.*wanted = (.*),.*/\1/p')"`

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using tcsh

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `bash` or similar, don't use `set` to assign values to variables (that was a (t)csh syntax). In fact, there's no keyword for it:

```
pa=disk/file1
```

What `set` does when it sees parameter it can't parse is it assigns it to the next positional parameter. For example,

```
set pa=disk/file1
```

sets `$1` to `pa=disk/file1`. (Easily verifiable by `echo "$1"`.)